# Move box Continously on left and right button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

trying to move `.popup` class on button left and right continuously move left to right and right to left..

[Here is js fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mkmishra19/gJbz9/1/)

HTML:

```
<button class="right">Right</button>
<button class="left">Left</button>
<div class="popup">
    Popup
</div>
```

Comment: I don't get exactly what you're trying to do, could you explain a little more?

Answer (score 1):

you have missed left property of .popup div

```
 .popup {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px dashed #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left:0px;
 }
```

You could improve your script as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var left = parseInt($(".popup").css('left'));
    var refreshIntervalId;
    $(".left").on('mousedown', function () {
        refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function () {
            $('#counter').html(parseInt($('#counter').html()) + 1);
            left += 5;
            $(".popup").css({"left": left})
        }, 10);
    })
    $(".left").on('mouseup', function () {
        clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
    })
    $(".right").on('mousedown', function () {
        refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function () {
            $('#counter').html(parseInt($('#counter').html()) - 1);
            left -= 5;
            $(".popup").css({"left": left});
        }, 10);
    })
    $(".right").on('mouseup', function () {
        clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
    })
});
```